# Constructor with not initialized final class variables

Tags: dart, constructor, final

I have this class:

```
class Entry {
  final String id;
  final List<ListEntry> listEntries;

  Entry({this.listEntries}):
        id = Uuid().v4();

  Entry.withId({this.id, this.listEntries});
}
// create new class instance
var e = Entry();
```

Now when I call any method on `e.listEntries` I will get a NPE because it is not initialized. Is there a way to have it default to an empty list in case the constructor argument is not provided?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Factory constructor:

```
class Entry {
  final String id;
  final List<String> listEntries;

  factory Entry({List<String> listEntries}) {
    return Entry._(listEntries ?? []);
  }

  Entry._(this.listEntries):
        id = Uuid().v4();

  Entry.withId({this.id, this.listEntries});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize the field in the initializer list instead of using `this.ListEntries` (an initializing formal).

```
class Entry {
  final String id;
  final List<ListEntry> listEntries;

  Entry({List<ListEntry> listEntries})
      : this.withId(id: Uuid().v4(), listEntries: listEntries);

  Entry.withId({this.id, this.listEntries}) 
      : listEntries = listEntries ?? [];
}
// create new class instance
var e = Entry();
```

Here I reuse the `Entry.withId` constructor so I only have to write things once.